# PostgreSQL Query to select data from last week?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has all the purchases of my costumers. I want to select all entries from the last week, (week start from Sunday).

```
id    value  date
5907  1.20   "2015-06-05 09:08:34-03"
5908  120.00 "2015-06-09 07:58:12-03"
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT id, valor, created, FROM compras WHERE created >= now() - interval '1 week' and parceiro_id= '1'
```

But I got the data from the last week including data from this week, I only want data from the last week.

How to get data only from last week ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This condition will return records from Sunday till Saturday last week:

```
WHERE created BETWEEN
    NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INTEGER-7 
    AND NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW from NOW())::INTEGER
```

There is an example:

```
WITH compras AS (
    SELECT ( NOW() + (s::TEXT || ' day')::INTERVAL )::TIMESTAMP(0) AS created
    FROM generate_series(-20, 20, 1) AS s
)
SELECT to_char( created, 'DY'::TEXT), created
FROM compras
WHERE created BETWEEN
    NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INTEGER-7 
    AND NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW from NOW())::INTEGER
```

**In answer to @d456:**

> Wouldn't using `BETWEEN` include midnight on Sunday at both ends of the interval?

That right, `BETWEEN` includes midnight on Sunday at both ends of the interval. To exclude midnight on Sunday at end of interval it is necessary to use operators `>=` and `<`:

```
WITH compras AS (
    SELECT s as created
    FROM generate_series( -- this would produce timestamps with 20 minutes step
             (now() - '20 days'::interval)::date,
             (now() + '20 days'::interval)::date,
             '20 minutes'::interval) AS s
)
SELECT to_char( created, 'DY'::TEXT), created
FROM compras
WHERE TRUE
    AND created >= NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INTEGER-7
    AND created <  NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW from NOW())::INTEGER
```

Comment: Thanks man, your answer helped me to get the last week and the week before last week. :)

Comment: Wouldn't using `BETWEEN` include midnight on Sunday at both ends of the interval?

Comment: @d456, thank you for your notice. Your are right. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 31):

Postgres by default starts weeks on a Sunday, so you are in luck.  You can use `date_trunc()` to get the beginning of the previous week:

```
WHERE (created >= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '1 week') and
       created < date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
      )
```

EDIT:

Postgres by default starts week for *date_trunc* on Monday, but for dow on Sunday.  So, you can do what you want by using that logic, which Nicolai has in his answer.

Comment: Thanks man :D.One more question.What if I want the week before last week ? I mean, I'll need to get data from the week before last week and so on.

Comment: FYI the [Postgres 9.6 docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html) say that the week begins by default on Monday, not Sunday (in keeping with ISO-8601.)  I did verify that it is so.

Comment: @user9645 . . . I see that.  It is interesting that extracting DOW starts the week on Sunday.

Comment: Even if you want to do Sunday to Sunday as your week, you can still use date_trunc as above, then just subtract another day from the result with `- interval '1 day'`