# Creating a PostgreSQL `tsrange` from two timestamps

Tags: postgresql, range, common-table-expression

I am trying to create a `tsrange` (last Thursday to the previous Thursday) in a postgresql query but I get cast errors.

This is what I have got so far (starting off from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30784305/222529)).

```
WITH past_week AS (
    SELECT date_trunc('day', NOW() + (s::TEXT || ' day')::INTERVAL)::TIMESTAMP(0) AS day 
    FROM generate_series(-7, 0, 1) AS s)
SELECT (
date_trunc('day', (SELECT day FROM past_week WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM day) = '4') - '7 day'::INTERVAL),
date_trunc('day', (SELECT day FROM past_week WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM day) = '4')));
```

And this is the result (correct value, but not format, since it's not a range):

```
                      row                      
-----------------------------------------------
 ("2015-10-29 00:00:00","2015-11-05 00:00:00")
(1 row)
```

Now, there are 2 main things that bug me:

1. If I try and add a `::tsrange` right before the end of the query, the interpreter complains that:

   ERROR:  cannot cast type record to tsrange
   LINE 6: ...ROM past_week WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM day) = '4')))::tsrange;
2. I would love to avoid repetition, but I'm not that proficient in SQL to know how. Any improvement is more than welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [tsrange() constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT):

```sql
WITH past_week AS (
    SELECT date_trunc('day', NOW() + (s::TEXT || ' day')::INTERVAL)::TIMESTAMP(0) AS day 
    FROM generate_series(-7, 0, 1) AS s)
SELECT tsrange(
    date_trunc('day', 
        (SELECT day FROM past_week 
        WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM day) = '4') - '7 day'::INTERVAL),
    date_trunc('day', 
        (SELECT day FROM past_week 
        WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM day) = '4')));
```

You can look for the past Thursday instead of the past week to simplify the query:

```sql
WITH past_thursday AS (
    SELECT current_date- extract(DOW FROM current_date)::int- 3 AS thursday
    )
SELECT tsrange(thursday- interval '7d', thursday)
FROM past_thursday;
```

or, using a derived table:

```sql
SELECT tsrange(thursday- interval '7d', thursday)
FROM (
    SELECT current_date- extract(DOW FROM current_date)::int- 3 AS thursday
) past_thursday;
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/GIjgnBGC)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Would there also be a way to avoid writing twice `(SELECT day FROM past_week WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM day) = '4')`?

Comment: You could put that into another WITH.