# get data from last week monday to last week sunday in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a request which must be formulated as follows in postgresql:

```
SELECT AVG(voltage) FROM TABLE1,TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.id=TABLE2.table1_id AND recharged BETWEEN last_week_monday AND last_week_sunday
GROUP BY TABLE1.name
```

I want to know how to get **last_week_monday** and **last_week_sunday**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL Query to select data from last week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783452/postgresql-query-to-select-data-from-last-week)

Comment: `SELECT (NOW() + interval '1 hour') AS last_week_sunday;`  just change this to suite your needs [NOW](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-now/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses `DATE_TRUNC`:

```sql
SELECT AVG(voltage)
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
WHERE recharged >= DATE_TRUNC('week', NOW()) - interval '7 day' AND
      recharged < DATE_TRUNC('week', NOW());
```

Postgres' `DATE_TRUNC()` function treats Monday as the start of the week.