# I want to make a query upload data for the previous week

Tags: postgresql

please help me write a query. so that instead of payment_date >= '2023-01-01', a report for the previous week, from Monday to Sunday, is uploaded, a formula is needed so that the values are not prescribed each time,  **It confuses me that the data type of the payment_date column is text**

this is my example:

```
select region, cstate_code as, count(code), count(e_code), count(contr_code) 
from REGULAR_CODE a
  join DEAL_PARTS b
    on a.realty_code = b.realty_code
  left join REGION_NUMBER
    on split_part(b.cadastr, ':', 1)::varchar = rc.cadastr_code
where status_name = finished and payment_date >= '2023-01-01'
group by region
order by region asc
```

Comment: The answer here should do the trick: [get data from last week monday to last week sunday in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69977457/get-data-from-last-week-monday-to-last-week-sunday-in-postgresql)